# does "concentration" refers to being "luminous"?

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

does "never" applies both for "think" and "is so intensely consciouss"?

It was this etheric body which Davis saw emerging from its poor
outworn envelope of protoplasm, which finally lay empty upon the bed
like the shrivelled chrysalis when the moth is free. **The process began by
an extreme concentration in the brain, which became more and more
luminous as the extremities became darker**. It is probable that man
never thinks so clearly, or is so intensely conscious, as he becomes after
all means of indicating his thoughts have left him. Then the new body
begins to emerge, the head disengaging itself first. Soon it has
completely freed itself, standing at right-angles to the corpse, with its
feet near the head, and with some luminous vital band between which
corresponds to the umbilical cord.

Comment: "Man never thinks so clearly...as...after all means (ways) of indicating his thoughts have left him." That is, after he is no longer able to express his thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're right.

It doesn't make sense taking the *is so intensely conscious* outside the *never*, because the structure is

> (It is probable that) man is **never** ... **so** ... **as**  he becomes after ...

The *so* is repeated in each clause, so they are parallel inside that structure.